# how execute comand inside terminal and use the terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

i read others webs, but i don't work 
e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the
openvt -- terminator -e cmatrix 
terminator -e cmatrix
i want to run cmatrix when i open my terminal and used the terminal  when cmatrix exit.
the terminal that use  is terminator i changed preferences  when commands exit hold the terminal open but when exit cmatrix for use terminal, the terminal don't work, and if i use this configuration the  exit command put in pause the terminal, any idea how execute commands in terminal and when exit use the terminal

Comment: Who on the planet upvoted this? It's completely unreadable.

Comment: Heidegger is "completely unreadable", this is a fair question. He wants to run a program, and have an active shell after if finishes running. However, when he targets a terminal emulator at the program, it closes when the program exits. He wants it to remain "open".

Comment: Do you mean stay open like a run-on sentence?

Comment: the planet is mordor (joke), sorry I will improve my English

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running a program directly, say `foo`, you can run a script with this kind of content:

```
cd some/directory
foo
bash
```

After `foo` finishes, `bash` will start and you'll have an open shell.

Answer (score 0):

openvt -- terminator -e "bash -c \"cmatrix; exec bash\""